# Storing Checked Radio buttons values in Jquery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in HTML with `n number` of rows with same sex radio buttons in `0th` position of `<td>`. I want to store values of sex (either `1` or `0`) in an array. Here is sample code for `3-rows`.

**HTML Code:**

```
<table>
<tr><td>

Male <input type="radio" name="sex" value="0"/> 
Female  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="1"/> 

</td></tr>
<tr><td>

Male <input type="radio" name="sex1" value="0"/> 
Female  <input type="radio" name="sex1" value="1"/>

</td></tr>
<tr><td>

Male <input type="radio" name="sex2" value="0"/> 
Female  <input type="radio" name="sex2" value="1"/> 

</td></tr>
 </table>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
var get_sex = new Array();
 $("table").find('tr').each(function (i) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td');
        get_sex[i] = $tds.eq(0).text();
    });
    $("#result").html(get_sex);
```

**Output I get:**

Male Female,Male Female,Male Female

**Output I want:**

1,0,1

Where **1** is checked Male and **0** is checked Female

Comment: I think that is just a JavaScript array.

Comment: @Patrick Yes Its Javascript array, But can you help me to get only checked values from each row of sex radio buttons.

Comment: Of course. Answered already ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `text`:

```
get_sex[i] = $tds.eq(0).val();
```

Comment: I also tried this, but its not checking which is checked.
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/p5sWb/

Comment: Will take a look for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can map() the values to an array

```
var get_sex = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y76Be/3/)

Comment: In a way your answer is correct but I am confused how to wrap your code with mine code :\

Comment: I haven't seen your code, so I can't really tell you? To just output the array you can do `$("#result").html(get_sex.join(', '));`